# Alinhamento DIV Bootstrap

Tags: html, div, layout-responsivo, css

Usei o código que o @hugocsl me indicou e ficou alinhado, mas agora fica minúsculo no responsivo. Usei o min-width e funcionou!

.mapa img {
    float: left;
    border:1px solid;
}
.mapa {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

```
<div class="row mapa">
    <div class="">
        <a href="">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9OVp.png" title="Goiania" style="display:block">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <a href="">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvW7B.png" title="Brasília" style="display:block">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <a href="">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbYRO.png" style="display:block">
        </a>
```

Comment: Creio que você ainda está com dúvidas em relação ao sistema de Grid do bootstrap, de uma olha nesse tutorial do w3s https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp em inglês(recomendo usar o tradutor do chrome caso não compreenda, a tradução nesse caso é boa), que irá te ajudar bastante

Comment: Outro problema que estou tendo é que fica parcialmente alinhado no smartphone e completamente desalinhado no computador.

Comment: Olá Lila. Você pode editar sua pergunta clicando no link "editar" logo abaixo de onde aparecem as tags (`html`,`css`) edit e incluir esse texto lá, fica mais legível.
Quanto ao seu problema não consegui replicar, pelo menos não no computador. Copiei seu código e coloquei no *jsfiddle*, veja como está: https://jsfiddle.net/Pontual/aq9Laaew/54779/

Comment: Sua réplica ficou alinhada, exatamente como preciso, mas a página não fica de jeito nenhum!

Comment: Então o problema pode ser outros atributos da página, ou até as referências para o `bootstrap`. Inclua o código html completo da sua página na poergunta, incluindo o `head` também. Clique nesse link para editar sua pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/309700/edit

Comment: Qual a finalidade de colocar os pedaços das imagens no grid? Não seria melhor usa-las fora do Grid? Qual a sua intenção em montar o mapa com o Grid?

Comment: Eu preciso transformar um mapa em links para acesso a diferentes regiões e essa foi a única forma que consegui fazer.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Ele executa o head e não mostra o código, mas eu limpei a página por completo deixando apenas a chamada do Bootstrap.
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TESTE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

Comment: Dê uma olhada novamente no link que montei o [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pontual/aq9Laaew/54779/)  do lado esquerdo tem um ícone com o número "5", clicando lá você vai ver todas as referências do `bootstrap` que usei. Tirando o *font-awesome.min.css* e o *popper.min.js*, as outras 3 tem que estar no seu site, me parece que você está esquecendo alguma biblioteca. O `bootstrap` tem um arquvo **.js** e um **.css** e também o **jquery**, veja se isso não está faltando no seu `head`

Comment: @RicardoPontual Usei um código indicado aqui pelo hugocsl e ficou alinhado, agora só preciso ajustar o tamanho no responsivo, pois o mapa ficou minúsculo. Eu havia tirado as referências para testar o alinhamento. Muito obrigada!

Comment: @LilaBastos se esta usando bootstrap não vejo porque criar um grid do zero, como a resposta do hugocsl sugeri, é melhor usar logo o pronto do bootstrap e ler as respostas indicadas nos links que eu e o Bacco lhe enviamos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não necessariamente precisa colocar as imagens dentro do Grid, vc pode separa-las apenas pelas ROWs como vc fez.

Com apenas algumas linhas de CSS vc consegue alinhar tudo, deixei as imagens com uma borda apenas para vc ver que elas continuam divididas.

```css
.mapa img {
    float: left;
    border:1px solid;
}
.mapa {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="container">
    <div class="row mapa">
        <div class="">
            <a href="">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Vzl.png" title="" style="display:block">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <a href="">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHQpz.png" style="display:block">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <a href="">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhGD3.png" style="display:block">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mapa">
        <div class="">
            <a href="">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9OVp.png" title="Goiania" style="display:block">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <a href="">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvW7B.png" title="Brasília" style="display:block">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <a href="">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbYRO.png" style="display:block">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mapa">
        <div class="">
            <a href="">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmrvy.png" title="São Paulo" style="display:block">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <a href="">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9S77.png" title="Resende" style="display:block">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <a href="">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBYFr.png" title="Rio de Janeiro" style="display:block">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hugo com esse código consegui alinhar, mas no responsivo ele fica minúsculo. Um min-width resolve?

Comment: @LilaBastos edita sua resposta com uma imagem de como está na sua tela ou o código completo de como está no momento. Aqui eu testei e não ficou pequeno não, na verdade a imagem começa a cortar quando a tela fica menor que 375px de largura

Comment: Funcionou com min-width! Muitíssimo obrigada.

Comment: @LilaBastos legal que deu certo!! Se a sua dúvida já foi respondida considere marcar uma resposta como aceita, nesse ícone `✔` a lado da resposta que vc usou, assim a pergunta não fica pendente no site como Pergunta sem Reposta Aceita. Boa sorte com o projeto

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o problema é que você não está respeitando as 12 colunas.
8 + 1 + 2 = 11
tente colocar mais 1 em algum lugar como 9 + 1 + 2, ou 8 + 1 + 3 que deve resolver

Answer (score 0):

Segue a regra de classes para cada tipo de tela

maiores que 576 classe .col-sm-

maiores que 768 classe .col-md-

maiores que 992 classe .col-lg-

maiores que 1200 classe .col-xl-

Você pode combinar os valores, exemplo em uma div utilizar col-sm-12 e col-lg-6 no caso o resultado seria em telas maiores que 576 até 992 iria criar 12 colunas e em telas maiores iria ficar com 6 colunas

Veja a documentação no site https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
Ela explica bem certo essas etapas